# Excel formula to calculate last 3 weekdays

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Is there any Excel functions that can populate the last 3 weekdays in 3 cells?

Like:

```
A1=7/9/2012
A2=7/6/2012
A3=7/5/2012
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method #1

You could try these formulas in 3 cells:

```
=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-1)

=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-2)

=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-3)
```

### Method #2

This formula will return the last nTH weekday/workday.

```
=TODAY()-CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(TODAY()),2,3,n,n,n,n,n)
```

Examples:

```
=TODAY()-CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(TODAY()),2,3,1,1,1,1,1)

=TODAY()-CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(TODAY()),2,3,2,2,2,2,2)

=TODAY()-CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(TODAY()),2,3,3,3,3,3,3)
```

--

If `TODAY()` were 7/09/2012 (a Monday), the first formula for both methods would return 7/6/2012 (a Friday).

To see the days of the week along with the dates, try the following number formats:

- `ddd mm/dd/yyyy`
- `dddd mmmm d, yyyy`
- `dddd`

Comment: I did this whole work around using ifs and weekday function and forgot about workday. :/ Tested and worked.

Comment: @CameronAziz It's also possible with the weekday() function.

Comment: ya, I did it quick and dirty: =IF(WEEKDAY((TODAY()-1),1)=6, (TODAY()-2), IF(WEEKDAY((TODAY()-1),1)=7, (TODAY()-3), (TODAY()-1)))